# playframework 2 - empty string for optional form field

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form

```
case class UserUpdateForm(
  id:Long, name: String, 
  remark: Option[String], location: Option[String])
```

I define the fields as

```
"id" -> of[Long],
"remarks" -> optional(text)
```

the remark field is  `None`,  Not `Some("")` I am excepting,

> So, how can I bind an empty string to optional text field

Comment: I think you can not bind empty string to optional text field, it is desired effect when field is empty, give us more insight maybe your use case can be resolved differently

Comment: @grotrianster I want to update remarks field if the remarks is not `None`。If it is None, I consider we don't want to update that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case class OptionalText(wrapped: Mapping[String], val constraints: Seq[Constraint[Option[String]]] = Nil) extends Mapping[Option[String]] {
    override val format: Option[(String, Seq[Any])] = wrapped.format
    val key = wrapped.key

    def verifying(addConstraints: Constraint[Option[String]]*): Mapping[Option[String]] = {
      this.copy(constraints = constraints ++ addConstraints.toSeq)
    }

    def bind(data: Map[String, String]): Either[Seq[FormError], Option[String]] = {
      data.keys.filter(p => p == key || p.startsWith(key + ".") || p.startsWith(key + "[")).map(k => data.get(k)).collect { case Some(v) => v }.headOption.map { _ =>
        wrapped.bind(data).right.map(Some(_))
      }.getOrElse {
        Right(None)
      }.right.flatMap(applyConstraints)
    }

    def unbind(value: Option[String]): (Map[String, String], Seq[FormError]) = {
      val errors = collectErrors(value)
      value.map(wrapped.unbind(_)).map(r => r._1 -> (r._2 ++ errors)).getOrElse(Map.empty -> errors)
    }

    def withPrefix(prefix: String): Mapping[Option[String]] = {
      copy(wrapped = wrapped.withPrefix(prefix))
    }

    val mappings: Seq[Mapping[_]] = wrapped.mappings
  }

  val textOpt = new OptionalText(text)
```

Finally I copied the OptionalMapping class and exclude the empty filter part

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same thing some months ago. I didn't find any easy way around it, so I decided to play along.

Basically, `"remarks" -> optional(text)`
will always return `None` when `text` is an empty string. So instead of treating an empty string as a sign of no updates, fill the `remarks` field in the form with the original value and then, after you get it back:

```
remarks match {
  case None => // set remarks to ""
  case originalRemark => // do nothing
  case _ => // set remarks to the new value
}
```

Hope it helps. It's my first entry here, on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: May be you can have a look at my answer above, that works , I have tested it

Comment: Yeah, it's good too, but a bit too complicated for my liking.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```scala
"remarks" -> default(text, "")
```